# Tkinter - Dynamically add and delete values from one combobox based on another combobox selection

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I have two Ttk comboboxes, both of them with the exact same values: A, B, C, D. I need to delete from one of them the value I selected on the other one, and, if I change my selection, I want that deleted value back and delete the new value. This is to prevent from choosing the same value on both combos.

That is:

**On combo1 I select A. Delete A from combo2.


Then I select B on combo1. Add A into combo2; delete B from it.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please check my edit on the post. I worked it out! Hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: Instead of editing your own post to fit in the answer, can you post the working code as an answer and mark it as the answer yourself?

Comment: Just did it! \m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution can be simplified as below:

```
def update_combos(self, event):
    self.cmb_group1["values"] = [x for x in self.lst_combo if x != self.cmb_group2.get()]
    self.cmb_group2["values"] = [x for x in self.lst_combo if x != self.cmb_group1.get()]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! There's so much Python for me to learn! \m/

Comment: Yes I am still learning as well and programming in Python is fun.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it works perfectly. It even keeps the original order in both combos.
This is what I did:

```
def update_combos(self, event):
    if self.cmb_group1.get() in self.cmb_group2["values"]:
        index = self.lst_combo.index(self.cmb_group1.get())
        self.lst_combo.remove(str(self.cmb_group1.get()))
        self.cmb_group2["values"] = self.lst_combo
        self.lst_combo.insert(index,self.cmb_group1.get())

    if self.cmb_group2.get() in self.cmb_group1["values"]:
        index = self.lst_combo.index(self.cmb_group2.get())
        self.lst_combo.remove(str(self.cmb_group2.get()))
        self.cmb_group1["values"] = self.lst_combo
        self.lst_combo.insert(index,self.cmb_group2.get())
```

I hope this could be useful for anyone! Should you have any sugestions to make this code even better, I'll gladly take your advice!

Comment: Hi, im having the same issue. Where are you adding this function to? I cant see your full code at the top of the screen as well. Do you still remember how you did it?